# One loop with all lists in one instead of two loops with separated lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an algorithmic question. Sorry if it seems to you silly.

Consider I have two lists:

```py
list_a = ["Red", "Blue", "Black"]
list_b = ["Samsung", "Apple"]
```

So the question is, if I iterate through the lists above with two `for` loop is faster or merging them and using just one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: 2 for loops is faster if you aren't nesting them(and also space efficient).

Comment: Also itertools library is written in C and is normally very fast, there are examples in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Easy to find out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: A good choice that combines efficiency and cleanness is [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the goal is to just iterate elements of both collections (and not to produce and iterate some kind of Cartesian product) and if we are talking Big-O notation then from algorithmic point of view it does not matter - both will require O(m+n) (where m and n are length of `list_a` and `list_b` respectively) operations. The actual speed will be implementation specific, for example if you do something like `list_a.extend(list_b)` and then will iterate - then it will be slower due to the need to move elements (for simplicity we can consider it to be O(n)) but if you will be using some lazy iterable approach (for example [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as mentioned by [@Jorge Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12575557/jorge-luis)) then the speed should be comparable.

In some cases you can "reduce" the Big-O to O(max(m, n)) by iterating them in one cycle for min(m, n) elements and then finishing the longer one in separate loop (*pseudocode* to get the idea):

```
longest = list_a if len(list_a) > len(list_b) else list_b

for i in range(min(len(list_a), len(list_b))):
    print(list_a[i])
    print(list_b[i])

for j in range(i+1, max(len(list_a), len(list_b))):
    print(longest[j])
```

Which is similar to what [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) does (as correctly mentioned by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner))

Comment: Aside from this being invalid Python syntax, it ignores the fact that `zip` and `itertools.zip_longest` exist.

Comment: @chepner "Aside from this being invalid Python syntax" - that is specifically addressed in the answer  with _"pseudocode"_ remark.

Comment: Why provide pseudocode for a question that is explicitly tagged `python`?

Comment: @chepner because I'm a bit more fluent with pseudocode than with python and question starts from _"I have an algorithmic question."_

Comment: @chepner updated to valid python code.

Answer (score 0):

Imho it depends on what you're trying to accomplish with the iteration.

If you need to perform an operation on each combination of elements from list_a and list_b, such as creating a Cartesian product or a nested loop, then using two for loops is necessary. In this case, merging the lists would not be useful and may even cause errors in your code.

However, if you just need to iterate over all the elements in both lists sequentially, then merging them into one list and using a single for loop would be faster and more efficient.

Comment: _"then merging them into one list and using a single for loop would be faster and more efficient."_ -  can you please elaborate why?

Comment: I have measured all the ways possible and merging seems to be up to 20% slower.

Comment: @GuruStron
When you use two for loops, one for each list, you are essentially running two separate loops sequentially. Each loop has its own start and stop conditions, its own index variable, and its own set of iterations. This means that the computer has to perform more operations to keep track of the two loops separately, which can slow down the code.

Comment: I find it a bit of a cheat not to measure the time it takes to merge the two lists.

Comment: @Mime two combine two collections (unless you are using some lazy stuff like iterators, which can have it's own performance implications) you will need to iterate the second collection first and then iterate both. The "overhead" of having extra variable and extra jmp instructions is negligible compared. Either way you will need to perform m+n operations.

Comment: Two (explicit) loops are not necessary for a Cartesian product; that's what `itertools.product` is for.